# Clearing All Previous Styles on an Element and Applying New Ones

Tags: html, css, pug

I am currently merging functionality of 2-3 open-source projects and am dealing with a couple of large CSS files. To make a long story short, there are a couple of textboxes that are not being styled correctly. Namely, they seem to inherit styles from both libraries.

Hence, I am wondering if there is a Jade or CSS way of disabling all styles on those boxes and then applying only the ones indicated in its `class` property. That is, somehow I need to make sure that the only thing that are applied are those that are specified within the `class` property.

Comment: The `class` attribute does not specify styles. It's not clear what you want.

Comment: It does. By specifying classes.

Comment: `class` does not specify styles. In a stylesheet you can use `class` selectors to choose which elements you want to match. That's just a normal selector and there is no direct way to separate these selectors from the others.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out this link on 'unset', 'initial', and 'inherit'](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/all/).

Likewise, check this out as well.  There is always the option of [using '!important' in your own CSS](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) file to override existing styles.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

the [all property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) offers the ability to force a reset off all properties, but browser support is limited. Because of the nature of CSS, the element will always inherit any properties that are not overridden. I'm assuming if you are using jade you are also using a css pre-processor, so you can mange some of this by name-spacing your libraries. For example

```
//sass
.foo {
  @import 'bar';
}

//csss
.foo .class-from-bar {...}
.foo .class-from-bar-2 {...}
```